# How would I sync button disabled so refresh doesn't re-enable it

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm creating something where users need to wait X time before pressing the button again, but the problem is.. When you refresh the page, it's re-enabled.

I know this is possible, I'm just not to sure how.

Code: 
JS:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cool-down").on("click", function() {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            startCooldown();
        });
    });   

      function startCooldown() {
        alert("Your cooldown period has started. You will have to wait 3 hours before trying again.");
        //Disables magic button for 3 hours.
        setTimeout('$("#cool-down").removeAttr("disabled")', 12400000);
}
```

and my button is:

```
<input type="submit" id="cool-down" class="btn btn-default" value="Magic" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: @brk I tried to but It won't let me, it keeps saying indent it, but I did

Comment: I think you can set cookie to save button state and after refresh page get button state. jscookie it's a plugin ,you can work with cookie. https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: select code and press Ctrl+L to indent

Comment: @brk done, posted in main

Comment: @HamedJavaheri Thanks Ill look into it

Answer (score 0):

> When you refresh the page, it's re-enabled.

The reason is on refresh the `window` get refreshed & all variables will be refreshed and same with timer.

The possible solutions are maintain a cookie or maintain the button state in the server side

Answer (score 0):

You need to record whether client has click the button,

usually on server side, using cookie or session etc.

If your case is not that strict,here a tricky way using `localStorage`:

```
$("#cool-down").on("click", function() {
            var time = new Date().getTime();
            if (!localStorage.isClick || localStorage.isClick - time >= 12400000) {
               localStorage.isClick = time;
               dosomething();
               return;

            }
            donothing()
        });
```